# python3 import issue on PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm annoyed about the import logic when I write Python3 code in PyCharm Community Edition, Below is my structure.

```
project
├── orm.py
├── app.py
├── coroweb.py
```

in app.py, I import orm use below codes.

```
from . import orm
from .coroweb import xxx
```

It looks good in PyCharm, but when I run app.py, it will failed due to below error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'orm'
```

Then, I use related import like this.

```
import orm
from coroweb import xxx
```

it running good but has import error in PyCharm. It's `Unresolved reference`. I want to use code tracing in PyCharm, so I want to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: I guess `project` is not the root path in Pycharm, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try 2 things:

- `add __init__.py` file in your project directory
- right click on project and add project to Sources Root [image: p]